# img src doesn't work when I use local files

Tags: javascript, loops, animation, canvas

I've had problems with getting a rain effekt on my canvas. After some searching on google I found this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var ctx;
var imgBg;
var imgDrops;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var noOfDrops = 50;
var fallingDrops = [];

function setup() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasRegn');

    if (canvas.getContext) {
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                imgBg = new Image();
        imgBg.src = "http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/";
    setInterval(draw, 36);
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfDrops; i++) {
        var fallingDr = new Object();
        fallingDr["image"] =  new Image();
    fallingDr.image.src = "http://lorempixel.com/10/10/sports/";

        fallingDr["x"] = Math.random() * 600;
        fallingDr["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr);
        }

    }
}

   function draw() {
    drawBackground();

    for (var i=0; i< noOfDrops; i++)
    {
    ctx.drawImage (fallingDrops[i].image, fallingDrops[i].x, fallingDrops[i].y); //The rain drop

    fallingDrops[i].y += fallingDrops[i].speed; //Set the falling speed
    if (fallingDrops[i].y > 450) {  //Repeat the raindrop when it falls out of view
    fallingDrops[i].y = -25 //Account for the image size
    fallingDrops[i].x = Math.random() * 600;    //Make it appear randomly along the width    
    }

    }
}

function drawBackground(){  
    ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0); //Background
}

    </script>
```

The strange thing is that the code works as long as I don't change the image source from the link to my png-files. All I get is copies of my file drawn over and over again til the canvas's is full of lines.

Help please!

Comment: Are you using your own PNGs for background and drops ? It seems that the background is not drawn correctly.

Comment: It can depend on the browser. Last time I checked FF worked ok, but chrome had to be started with `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for some reason your background is not rendered.

If you don't want to have any background, you have to clear the canvas before drawing drops at their new positions, or else your canvas will flood :)

Replace: `ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0);`
with: `clearRect(0, 0, width, height)`

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/vTQLP/)**.

Comment: thx man. It did work without a background. The problem is that I really want my background :P Should I clear the canvas and then draw the picture?

Comment: If you are drawing an image, then you don't need to clear the canvas first. Are your PNGs hosted online or are you using files stored on your computer ?

Comment: I feel stupid. I think I've been sitting with this canvas for too long to notice that the background file was a .jpg xD problem solved!

Comment: Glad to hear it xD If this answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.